# Maxlength of textbox does not work in case of special characters

Tags: html, special-characters

I am facing an issue with maxlength attribute of a textbox. I have set it to 30 chars. But if I input special characters like 'å, ä, ö', it allows only 15 chars. These characters are counted as 2 chars each.

Did anybody face this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I am not facing any problem in this
Here's the code try it

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="10">
```

It is working fine with special characters also.

Comment: yes.You can try it at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_maxlength

Comment: hmm.. i tested this with test page and it works. don't know what I set in my project that blocks this...

Comment: I have the same issue it limiits the length but if your using a service the database will throw an error because the bytes of special characters are more. any solution?